# How to publish a asp.net application with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, publish

I'm developing a web application using asp.net and mysql. When i run it using visual studio it works fine. But when i'm trying to publish it following errors are coming.Please guide me what to do.

Message in Settings tab:
The database provider is not specified for this connection string. Incremental database publishing is supported only for SqlClient as well as Entity Framework code First models.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing using *.pubxml profile and if you not willing to do Database deploy (just code deploy), open your *.pubxml file and remove `<PublishDatabaseSettings>` section completely. Also remove any `MSDeployParameterValue` tags containing references to your connection string. This will allow you to publish the code.